# Github Merge Fail due to unmerged files

Tags: git, love2d

So I've been working on a Love2D project, and Nixola helped me with a code issue (check out my post about it [here](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=80396&p=185616#p185616)) but he pulled my code on Github [here](https://github.com/tom7tomm/SuperDodger) and then I merged his code into my repo. At the same time as this I was writing a bit more code, but I did not sync as soon as I merged Nixola's code. It then made duplicates of most of my code, so I deleted the Code I didn't want. I then tried to sync the code, but it gives this error:

> Failed to sync this branch due to unmerged files
>
> It appears that you may be in a merge conflict. Open the Get Shell and
>   resolve the conflicts in your working directory before attempting to
>   sync again.

How can I fix this and get my repo back to a working state?

Comment: It error is saying you have merged some code/files from others. After that some conflicts took place in your code due to the merge. All you need to do is see which files has conflicts , open those files and resolve the conflicts.  

If you have full trace on the command line after the merge please paste that.

Comment: I've done that, but It still gives the errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message. Please paste the entire message

Comment: I've made it so that it doesn't show any changes in the file, but it still won't sync.

Comment: Failed to sync this branch due to unmerged files

It appears that you may be in a merge conflict. Open the Get Shell and resolve the conflicts in your working directory before attempting to sync again.

Comment: That is all that it says

Answer (score 3):

Use `git status` to determine whether this is a traditional or deleted file conflict.

If this says "both modified", open the file in a text editor, resolve the conflicts which will be marked with `==========`, then `git add yourfile` and `git commit`.

If this says "deleted by ...", run `git rm yourfile` or `git add yourfile` with the correct contents, then `git commit`.

A complete walkthrough of the process is in the git documentation, here: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Additionally, if you just want to add all files, you can do `git add -A`